# Multi-level Dependent Drop Down Lists by Joomla 4 SQL Custom Field

Tags: joomla-4.x, mysql, custom-field

I need to create a Multi-level Dependent Drop Down List to show my Joomla Categories list in the first dropdown list and then show the related articles in the second dropdown list (based on the value of the first dropdown list) by SQL custom fields for Joomla articles.

the first dropdown list works properly and shows the categories:

```
SELECT title as text, id as value FROM #__categories WHERE extension = "com_content" and published=1;
```

But I don't know what SQL queries it needs for the second dropdown list to show the related articles and make the dependency to the first dropdown value.

The first SQL custom field name is category.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that Joomla by itself supports this, although I have seen extensions which claim to support what I believe you're looking for. Personally I'd implement your requirement in javascript - set an onchange listener on your category field which fires an ajax call to the server. In php code on the server get the articles associated with the selected category and pass them down in the json response, and then get the js to inject them into the second dropdown list.